# jquery shows "Loading" div at all times

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have code (that works in another ASP.Net application) that I've added to a very simple page. It's supposed to show a spinner with the word "Loading" when a button (btnSubmit) is clicked. What it's doing, however, is showing the spinner and "Loading" the instant the page loads. Here's the aspx page:

```html
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/default.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="SAM2.Test" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Main" runat="server">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowProgress() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        var modal = $('<div />');
        modal.addClass("modal");
        $('body').append(modal);
        var loading = $(".loading");
        loading.show();
        var top = Math.max($(window).height() / 2 - loading[0].offsetHeight / 2, 0);
        var left = Math.max($(window).width() / 2 - loading[0].offsetWidth / 2, 0);
        loading.css({
          top: top,
          left: left
        });
      }, 200);
    }
    
    $('form').live("submit", function() {
      ShowProgress();
    });
  </script>
  <div class="loading" align="center">
    Loading. Please wait.<br /><br />
    <img src="/images/ajax-loader.gif" />
  </div>
  <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbTest" />
  <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
</asp:Content>
```

In the code behind I have this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!IsPostBack)
  {
    string script = "$(document).ready(function () { $('[id*=btnSubmit]').click(); });";
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "load", script, true);
  }
}
```

I've tried adding this above the ShowProgress() function:

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
  $("#loading").hide();
});
```

but it doesn't help. As I said, this works in another application. I"m no jquery guru, so what am I missing?

Comment: Your registered startup script is triggering a click on the submit button which is in turn submitting the form, which shows the loader.

Comment: As I said, I'm no jquery guru. How do I fix that?

Comment: That isn't JS, it's in the C# you posted. Delete the `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` line, and by proxy the entire `Page_Load()` handler, if that's all it contains

Comment: Even if I comment out the ClientScript line, or even everything in Page_Load, the spinner still displays. How do I get it to display only after the btnSubmit has been pressed?

Answer (score 0):

The hide method can't find a "loading" ID. Set the div ID to "loading", you may need runat=server as well.

```
  <div class="loading" id="loading" runat="server" align="center">
```

Comment: Sorry, no. I added both id and runat but it still shows the instant the page loads. I just want to to show when I click on the Submit button.

Comment: Where is the fadeout() call?  Also be sure you have connection to the jquery files, try downloading them and referencing them locally to rule out conn issues.

Comment: Where should I put the fadeout() call? I'm really not very good at jquery, so I don't know....

Answer (score 0):

In your script tag call it in the load function. This should hide/ fadeout the div id 'loading' when page loads.

```
 <script>
    $(window).load(function () 
     {
        $('#loading').fadeOut();
    });  
 </script>
```

Comment: No, sorry. I add this to the top of my script block, but the spinner still appears immediately upon page load.